# Javascript Converting IETF Date to ISO8601 Format

Tags: javascript, datetime, date, data-conversion

I am using this awesome jQuery calendar plugin

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

One of the options for clicking on a date is a callback function to return the date that is clicked on.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/

I believe it only returns the date in this format IETF format - Wed, 18 Oct 2009 13:00:00 EST

I however, need it to be in ISO861 format to post the data.  I can't seem to find anything on it in google.  I am trying to convert it in Javascript.  If not, then conversion can take place in the Java backend.  Help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

From the [fine manual](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/):

> `date` holds a **Date object** for the current day.

Emphasis mine.

I'd guess that the IETF format you're seeing is just the default stringification of the `Date` object. The [Date class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) has `getYear()`, `getMonth()`, and `getDate()` methods so you can easily produce an ISO-8601 date string if you're careful with the zero-padding of course.

Answer (score 1):

Since dayClick gives you a Javascript Date object already, you can format it as an 8601 formatted date string using [this function from the Mozilla site.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Example.3a_ISO_8601_formatted_dates)

Answer (score 0):

it returns a regular javascript date object. you can use the fullcalendar `formatDate` utility function with it like this:

```
$.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'u');
```

[full docs for formatDate](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the formatDate function belong on your Date object dayClick!

```
function getGMTOffset(localDate) {
    var positive = (localDate.getTimezoneOffset() > 0);
    var aoff = Math.abs(localDate.getTimezoneOffset());
    var hours = Math.floor(aoff / 60);
    var mins = aoff % 60;
    var offsetTz = padzero_(hours) + ':' + padzero_(mins);
    // getTimezoneOffset() method returns difference between (GMT) and local time, in minutes.
    // example, If your time zone is GMT+2, -120 will be returned.
    // This is why we are inverting sign
    if (!positive) {
      return '+' + offsetTz;
    }
    return '-' + offsetTz;
}

function pad2zeros(n) {
  if (n < 100) {
      n = '0' + n;
  }
  if (n < 10) {
      n = '0' + n;
  }
  return n;
}
function padzero(n) {
    return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n.toString();
}

function formatDate(date)  {
  if (date) {
    return (date.getFullYear()) +
           '-' + padzero((date.getMonth() + 1)) +
           '-' + padzero(date.getDate()) +
           'T' + padzero(date.getHours()) +
           ':' + padzero(date.getMinutes()) +
           ':' + padzero(date.getSeconds()) +
           '.' + pad2zeros(date.getMilliseconds()) +
           getGMTOffset(date);
  }
  return '';
}
```